# Very slow `INSERT` transactions on the resourcepaths table

Tags: database, performance, mysql, yii, load-balancer

After a recent update (Craft 3.4.x to 3.5.x) I'm seeing some suspiciously slow response times in relation to `INSERT` actions on the `resourcepaths` table. Some in the upwards of a half second for a single transaction.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? One note, this is hosted on a load-balanced environment so I'm not sure if this plays into this (if at all).

[image: Yii debug toolbar showing slow durations for the INSERT transactions in the craft_resourcepaths table]

Comment: This issue is happening to me as well but using a PostgreSQL, did you find any solutions @Aaron Bushnell?

Comment: I'm on Craft 3.7.21 and just experienced something similar. Except the UPSERT queries were taking up to a minute or more, and taking down my site. Did you ever find a reason or solution to this one